# GRASS init error: GRASS was not found in 'INVALID/S/qgis-deps-0.9/stage/grass78' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have downloaded QGIS 3.26.3 from https://www.qgis.org/en/site/ and installed it on my Mac M1 Pro running OS 12.6

On launching QGIS I get the following initialization error:

"*GRASS init error: GRASS was not found in 'INVALID/S/qgis-deps-0.9/stage/grass78' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.*"

Under Plugins Menu / Grass / Grass Options I can see that QGIS has got confused and by default is looking in an invalid place.
[image: screenshot]

Choosing the "Custom" option doesn't help, and I get a similar initialization error at start up:

"*GRASS init error: GRASS was not found in '/Applications/QGIS 5.app/Contents/Resources/grass78' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.*"

The grass78 folder exits at that location, and although it has files in it, QGIS still cannot find what its looking for.
[image: screenshot2]

How can I get QGIS to find Grass?

I have tried deleting the installation and  trying again but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got around this by removing all installations of QGIS and then deleting everything on my Mac that had anything to do with qgis (finder search for qgis with system files included).

[image: screenshot]

....and then re-installing from a fresh download